# socket close in wait call from system - heartbeat mechanism

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, unix, aix

I have a heartbeat mechanism implemented where application 'app1' is sending pulse every 60 seconds to watchdog process 'watch1'. If watch1 doesnt get any message from app1 after 60 seconds it assumes that app1 is dead and it restarts it. But in acual it is alive. This comminication happens through TCP/IP sockets and applications running on same machine. The watch1 process listens on port say 3000 to read the packet from app1. These applications runs on multiple OSs UNix,AIX etc.

But for particular AIX machine the 'app1's socket is getting closed and the watch1 process restarting the app1 again and again. Its multithreading application where app1 creates one thread to send message/packet to watch1.

I put in place a script which every 60 seconds ran ‘procstack’ on the app1 PID to see what was going on. This didn’t provide any pointers I’d hoped for (like being stuck on a lock), rather it began to show some ‘weird’ stack patterns:

```
 ---------- tid# 21692655 (pthread ID:   3342) ----------
 0xd4be4754  SocketBase::close()(0x0) + 0x34 
 0xd0503ca4  _event_wait(??, ??) + 0x2c4
 0xd0511e78  _cond_wait_local(??, ??, ??) + 0x378
 0xd05125d0  _cond_wait(??, ??, ??) + 0xb0
 0xd0512f1c  pthread_cond_timedwait(??, ??, ??) + 0x21c
 0xd4a2cbd8  TaskEvent::Wait(int)(0x32ebc03c, 0x7530) + 0xd8
 0xd4e40b70  SendIAmAliveThreadFunc(void*)(0x32ebc038) + 0xf50
 0xd3dfcdc4  ThreadStartRoutine(void*)(0x32ebbba8) + 0xc4
 0xd04f0c4c  _pthread_body(??) + 0xec
```

It makes no sense that the kernel service _event_wait() would be calling our code(wrapper class for socket handling) SocketBase::close(). Might be some weird anomaly; might need some AIX expertise to help diagnose.

Is any one aware of this issue or guide on this?

*********** EDIT1 - 23-11-12 **********

The app1 process is getting terminated with signal 15.

Logs:
Received signal 15 on thread 515
Thread 515 does not handle signal 15
Abnormal termination due to signal 15kill: 7143518: no such process
Start command failed.
kill: 7405740: no such process

warning: The core file is not a fullcore. Some info may
not be available.

Comment: Seems like you hit a deadlock in your process. Check what more waits on the same "thing" that your `SendIAmAliveThreadFunc`.

Comment: Are you sure it's a debug build? There could well be stack frames optimized out with -O2 or equivalent, though I don't use xlc often enough to know its behaviour here.

Comment: Also, they're running on the same machine, so you don't need the heartbeat. Just make a unix domain socket connection (or TCP, but why?), and send nothing over it (either with socketpair before fork/execing app1, or bind in the watchdog and connect from the app). When the application process dies, the kernel closes its end of the socket and the watchdog will be signalled (zero read).

This is a standard way of waiting on an unrelated process in unix. No data needs to go over the wire. In any case, you shouldn't need to mess with threads to get this working.

Comment: Another asynchronous method to test for a process existence is to send a zero signal from the watch1 process to see if the target process is alive:  kill(pid, 0).  In reality this does not send a signal, it tests for the existence of the target process.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but the wathcdog is generic in nature means any application can register itself to it for monitoring. Also i forgot to mention that, the app1 doesnt simply send alive signal; also it sends some info like startCommand, stopCommand etc..this data(in form of string) needs to be reached to watch1. As there are multiple tasks to be executed by the app1 this has to be done in thread and architecure demands this.

Comment: @Pingala What does your TaskEvent::Wait do ? From the stack trace it appears to be waiting on a condition variable. The SocketBase::Close()  seems rather arbitary, and you should't read too much into this, especially if it's a release build. You should check the state of the TCP connection as well, I assume AIX have `netstat` or something similar.

Comment: @ Nicholas Wilson: yes i also need to confirm the comiler optimization settings.@nos +1  , yes thats the conditional variable wait. I think you are right i should check the stus of TCP connection. But ,mostly i doubt that its might be some issue due to memory but not sure.